# Should I practice Anapana after 10 day Vipassana course?

Tags: vipassana, sn-goenka

I have completed 10-days Vipassana course and I would like to keep on practicing back home. Goenkaji's discourse tells us to practice Vipassana 1 hour each morning and evening every day.Is there a need to practice Anapana along with Vipassana if so how often?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource tab](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anapana in the context of the one hour sessions should be practiced if your mind not not calm, i.e., :

- Lot of distracting thoughts
- You are emotional
- Hindrances have come up
- etc.

It is always good to do about 5 to 15 minutes to start with, to calm your mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should practice Anapana ANY time of the day when you feel your attention needs to focus Here and Now, never forgetting Anicca, Anicca, Anicca. 
When you take the practice to daily live, including motion, while standing, eating, etc. After a while you will be able to do body scans in-motion too. 
It will be easy when you don't follow your stories (thoughts), simply gently go back to the sensations. Every time start again. The gaps will become shorter,

**you are bound to be successful!**